# Does backfocus/frontfocus change?

Tags: back-focus, front-focus, focus-adjust

I have adjusted the back-/frontfocus setting in my camera for different lenses.

Now I am wondering if I have to readjust the lenses regularly? Does the back-/frontfocus for a lens change much over time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No.** Well, I've never seen it happen.

If it does, I would suspect an imminent mechanical failure.

What I did see once is front or back focusing change between focus-distances. In that case the lens focuses well at one distance but is off at another. Since I've only see it once, it may a defect rather than tolerance error.

Comment: Thanks, then I know that I don't have to recalibrate them all the time. :)